# How to reduce clutter?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I'm writing a program where a user enters 8 different employees ages and desired age of retirement into an array and then im displaying that info along with the amount of years for them to retire. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Retirement {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

    int[][] ages = new int[8][2];
    System.out.println("Enter the employees current ages (between 19 and 70), and enter their desired retirement ages (62, 66, or 70).");
    for (int i = 0; i < ages.length; i++) {
        ages[i][0] = input.nextInt();
        ages[i][1] = input.nextInt();
        }
    int employee1 = (ages[0][1] - ages[0][0]);
    int employee2 = (ages[1][1] - ages[1][0]);
    int employee3 = (ages[2][1] - ages[2][0]);
    int employee4 = (ages[3][1] - ages[3][0]);
    int employee5 = (ages[4][1] - ages[4][0]);
    int employee6 = (ages[5][1] - ages[5][0]);
    int employee7 = (ages[6][1] - ages[6][0]);
    int employee8 = (ages[7][1] - ages[7][0]);

    System.out.println("The current age and desired retirement age for Employee #1 is: " + (ages[0][0]) + " and " + (ages[0][1]) + ".");
    System.out.println("Employee #1 has to work " + (employee1) + " years before they can retire.");

    System.out.println("\nThe current age and desired retirement age for Employee #2 is: " + (ages[1][0]) + " and " + (ages[1][1]) + ".");
    System.out.println("Employee #2 has to work " + (employee2) + " years before they can retire.");

    System.out.println("\nThe current age and desired retirement age for Employee #3 is: " + (ages[2][0]) + " and " + (ages[2][1]) + ".");
    System.out.println("Employee #3 has to work " + (employee3) + " years before they can retire.");

    System.out.println("\nThe current age and desired retirement age for Employee #4 is: " + (ages[3][0]) + " and " + (ages[3][1]) + ".");
    System.out.println("Employee #4 has to work " + (employee4) + " years before they can retire.");

    System.out.println("\nThe current age and desired retirement age for Employee #5 is: " + (ages[4][0]) + " and " + (ages[4][1]) + ".");
    System.out.println("Employee #5 has to work " + (employee5) + " years before they can retire.");

    System.out.println("\nThe current age and desired retirement age for Employee #6 is: " + (ages[5][0]) + " and " + (ages[5][1]) + ".");
    System.out.println("Employee #6 has to work " + (employee6) + " years before they can retire.");

    System.out.println("\nThe current age and desired retirement age for Employee #7 is: " + (ages[6][0]) + " and " + (ages[6][1]) + ".");
    System.out.println("Employee #7 has to work " + (employee7) + " years before they can retire.");

    System.out.println("\nThe current age and desired retirement age for Employee #8 is: " + (ages[7][0]) + " and " + (ages[7][1]) + ".");
    System.out.println("Employee #8 has to work " + (employee8) + " years before they can retire.");
}

}
```

Now, what I'm trying to figure out is if their may be a way to reduce some of this clutter, but I'm not sure if I can or if it just has to take up the space. It doesn't matter either way, but I'd like it to look a little more streamlined and not so cluttered. Thanks for any help!

Comment: it looks like java, not javascript.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't know their was a difference. I'm using eclipse, it probably is Java and not javascript, sorry.

Comment: That is kind of weird : you are fine using the twodim array for age... But it doesn't occur to you to use an array for employees too, and instead you have no problem writing down code 8 times?!

Comment: Meaning... Alone that you have var1 var2... Up to to var8 screams for arrays...

Answer (score 0):

I would start by making `employee` an array, and then a for loop can be created from there.

Comment: Hmm... I'm on break at work, after work I'll try this and post my code, I'll see if I can figure it out using that, im only slightly confused on how i'd get the numbers to increment each pass. Maybe assign them to a variable and increment it each pass? like age[t][0] and then declare t to a int = 0 and increment it. Would that work?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be able to use for loops already, so refactoring this code shouldn't be a problem:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

int[][] ages = new int[8][2];
int[] employees = new int[8];
System.out.println("Enter the employees current ages (between 19 and 70), and enter their desired retirement ages (62, 66, or 70).");
for (int i = 0; i < ages.length; i++) {
    ages[i][0] = input.nextInt();
    ages[i][1] = input.nextInt();
}
for (int i = 0 ; i < employees.length ; i++) {
    employees[i] = (ages[i][1] - ages[i][0]);
}

for (int i = 0 ; i < employees.length ; i++) {
    System.out.println("The current age and desired retirement age for Employee #" + (i + 1) + " is: " + (ages[i][0]) + " and " + (ages[i][1]) + ".");
    System.out.println("Employee #" + (i + 1) + " has to work " + (employees[i]) + " years before they can retire.");
}
```

To make it easier to access the employee variables, we put them in an array called `employees`.

Here's how to refactor the code:

Look for patterns! In these lines:

```
int employee1* = (ages[0*][1] - ages[0*][0]);
int employee2* = (ages[1*][1] - ages[1*][0]);
int employee3* = (ages[2*][1] - ages[2*][0]);
int employee4* = (ages[3*][1] - ages[3*][0]);
int employee5* = (ages[4*][1] - ages[4*][0]);
int employee6* = (ages[5*][1] - ages[5*][0]);
int employee7* = (ages[6*][1] - ages[6*][0]);
int employee8* = (ages[7*][1] - ages[7*][0]);
```

Do you realize that the parts with the `*` attached to it seem to increase by one each time, while all the other things remained unchanged? This means that we can turn this into a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < employees.length ; i++) {
    employees[i] = (ages[i][1] - ages[i][0]);
}
```

Now try to look for patterns in this code

```
System.out.println("The current age and desired retirement age for Employee #1 is: " + (ages[0][0]) + " and " + (ages[0][1]) + ".");
System.out.println("Employee #1 has to work " + (employee1) + " years before they can retire.");

System.out.println("\nThe current age and desired retirement age for Employee #2 is: " + (ages[1][0]) + " and " + (ages[1][1]) + ".");
System.out.println("Employee #2 has to work " + (employee2) + " years before they can retire.");

System.out.println("\nThe current age and desired retirement age for Employee #3 is: " + (ages[2][0]) + " and " + (ages[2][1]) + ".");
System.out.println("Employee #3 has to work " + (employee3) + " years before they can retire.");

System.out.println("\nThe current age and desired retirement age for Employee #4 is: " + (ages[3][0]) + " and " + (ages[3][1]) + ".");
System.out.println("Employee #4 has to work " + (employee4) + " years before they can retire.");

System.out.println("\nThe current age and desired retirement age for Employee #5 is: " + (ages[4][0]) + " and " + (ages[4][1]) + ".");
System.out.println("Employee #5 has to work " + (employee5) + " years before they can retire.");

System.out.println("\nThe current age and desired retirement age for Employee #6 is: " + (ages[5][0]) + " and " + (ages[5][1]) + ".");
System.out.println("Employee #6 has to work " + (employee6) + " years before they can retire.");

System.out.println("\nThe current age and desired retirement age for Employee #7 is: " + (ages[6][0]) + " and " + (ages[6][1]) + ".");
System.out.println("Employee #7 has to work " + (employee7) + " years before they can retire.");

System.out.println("\nThe current age and desired retirement age for Employee #8 is: " + (ages[7][0]) + " and " + (ages[7][1]) + ".");
System.out.println("Employee #8 has to work " + (employee8) + " years before they can retire.");
```

Again, you see that some of the numbers are increasing one by one while everything else remains unchanged. We can change this into a for loop as well:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < employees.length ; i++) {
    System.out.println("The current age and desired retirement age for Employee #" + (i + 1) + " is: " + (ages[i][0]) + " and " + (ages[i][1]) + ".");
    System.out.println("Employee #" + (i + 1) + " has to work " + (employees[i]) + " years before they can retire.");
}
```

However, the employee number doesn't increase from 0 to 7. Instead, it is from 1 to 8. That's why it is `"Employee #" + (i + 1)` instead of `"Employee #" + i`.

Comment: Okay, I tried this. I'm getting an error saying employee cannot be resolved to a variable. Nothing I do can seem to fix this. I've tried declaring the variable before hand but nothing seems to work. any tips?

Comment: Did you use the correct code? The very first code snippet is what you need. @senpaimaster

Comment: @senpaimaster I think you missed this line: `int[] employees = new int[8];`